# basename on buffer goes into segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, strcmp

I'm tweaking with `basename` right now and I encounter a case really weird (at least for me). Here's the code:

```
char buffer[300];
char* p;

strcpy(buffer, "../src/test/resources/constraints_0020_000");
printf("%d\n", strcmp(basename("../src/test/resources/constraints_0020_000"), "constraints_0020_000")); //works as expected
printf("assert testBasename02");
printf("%d\n", strcmp(basename(buffer), "constraints_0020_000") == 0);
printf("done 1\n"); //goes in segmentation fault
printf("%d\n", strcmp(basename(&buffer), "constraints_0020_000") == 0);
printf("done 2\n"); //goes in segmentation fault
printf("%d\n", strcmp(basename(&buffer[0]), "constraints_0020_000") == 0);
printf("done 3\n"); //goes in segmentation fault
p = malloc(strlen("../src/test/resources/constraints_0020_000") +1);
strcpy(p, "../src/test/resources/constraints_0020_000");
printf("%d\n", strcmp(basename(p), "constraints_0020_000") == 0); //works as expected
free(p);
printf("all done\n");
```

The first `strcmp` works totally as excepted; it is the second one that puzzles me: why a buffer would go in segmentation fault? I tried to code the buffer all in different ways but the result is the same.

I can of course live with this behaviour but... I don't really understand what is the difference for `basename` if i feed him a `const char*` or a buffer (that in the end is also a `char*`).

Is there a document that explain this behaviour? Is it just me? I tried to look for explanations but I couldn't find any.

Here the specification of my computer (if you need them):

- OS system: Ubuntu 16.4 (64 bit virtualized on Windows 10 64-bit);
- CPU (not that I think is useful): Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 2;

Comment: So can you trim your code to the failing case only?

Comment: yes! All the lines where the buffer and basename happens go in segmentation fault. I put in the code all the tests just to have all the scenarios. If you comment the lines with "buffer" and "basename" everything works fine. As soon as you decomment even one of them (doesn't matter which) the segmentation fault happen. I'm really puzzled

Comment: From `man basename`: "*Both dirname() and basename() may modify the contents of path, so it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of these functions.*". So you should not pass a string literal to it in the first place.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Ok, but the tests say just the opposite: if I use a constant string, it works; if I use an heap pointer, it works too; BUT if I use a heap buffer, it doesn't work anymore. Why?
I read that documentation... after debugging basename returns the address of the first character representing the basename itself.

Comment: As noted below - you can't reason about *undefined behavior*. Once you have one, anything can happen.

Comment: `free(p)` is missing a semicolon.  Your program seems to work for me with and without the lines causing undefined behavior.  http://ideone.com/v7Q2PS  What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: As I'm saying below, removing the call where I feed basename with a constant string does perfectly nothing: the segmentation fault still happens (but only if use a buffer). @Retired Ninja: thanks. I copied my code wrongly

Comment: @Retired Ninja: at the moment "gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609".

Comment: @Retired Ninja: ok, just compiled and execute your code on my machine: it goes into segmentation fault. Here's the compiation and the execution output: [link] (http://pastebin.com/8ifx6m3v)

Comment: @Koldar See latest comment under my answer. Add header files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename),

> #### Bugs
>
> In the glibc implementation of the POSIX versions of these functions they modify their argument, and segfault when called with a static string like `"/usr/"`. [...]

Basically,

```
 basename("../src/test/resources/constraints_0020_000")
```

invokes invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as this is an attempt to modify the string literal.

---

Note: As mentioned in the man page, there's a change of words needed. Read it like,

> *In the glibc implementation of the POSIX versions of these functions they modify their argument, and **invokes undefined behavior** when called with a static string like `"/usr/"`. [...]*

A segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB, but not the only one.

FWIW, attempt to modify a string literal itself invokes the UB. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

---

EDIT:

As discussed in follow up comments, an additional problem was missing header file. You need to have

```
  #include <libgen.h>
```

added so as to get the forward declaration of the function `basename()` available.

Comment: ok, but then the behaviour is even more weird: with a constant string it shouldn't work but the tests say otherwise. But if I use a variable buffer (according to the documentation it should work) basename goes in segmentation fault. Basically it behaves in the exact opposite manner!

Comment: @Koldar Please read the linked article, once a UB, always a UB. You cannot expect any _part_ of program to behave reasonable once your program hits UB.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh OK, I can agree with you that if the program executes an operation that leads to an undefined behaviour, all the next instructions may lead to an undefined behaviour as well. For that reason I explicitly removed the test where I fed basename with a constant string. With your logic the buffer should work now... but it is not! If you can, try it yourself, I'm not crazy, my mom tested me :)

Comment: @Koldar I really don;t see any problem apart from that. Can you please double-check?

Comment: @Koldar ___Please include `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>`___.

Comment: Incredible... I forgot to add <libgen.h>. Adding it solved the trouble. I thought being a system library I could avoid it but apparently omitting it creates unknown behaviour.... I'm shocked to realize this. Make an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131738/discussion-between-koldar-and-sourav-ghosh).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html):

> The `basename()` function may modify the string pointed to by `path`,
>   and may return a pointer to internal storage. The returned pointer
>   might be invalidated or the storage might be overwritten by a
>   subsequent call to `basename()`. The returned pointer might also be
>   invalidated if the calling thread is terminated.

Per [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html):

> Both **dirname()** and **basename()** may modify the contents of
>   `path`, so it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of
>   these functions.

You're calling `basename()` with a static string, which is likely read-only, thus causing a SEGV when `basename()` attempts to modify the string.