# Weird behavior of basename() on Mac OS

Tags: macos, clang, basename

I have a simple program to test basename() method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <libgen.h>

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    char *a = strdup("test();");
    printf("%s", basename(a));
    return 0;
}
```

clang complains but it compiles anyway.

```
test.c:7:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'basename' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("%p", basename(a));
                 ^
test.c:7:18: warning: format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%p", basename(a));
```

And it results in segfault. But if I added libgen.h header, it works normally.

I've checked the binary with otool, it linked against the same dylib, nothing else. Why does the first one crash?

I've checked [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367050/basename-on-buffer-goes-into-segmentation-fault) already, it uses a static buffer but I use the result from strdup(), so it's a different question.